# Panel visibility is not changing in timer tick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I am working on aspx web page in which two updatepanels are placed. In inner Updatepanel there is timer trigger is enabled and in that timer tick event i want to make a panel visible on specific condition. But unfortunately, the Panel's visibility is not changed. My code is as follows:-

```
protected void ChatTextTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (!worker1.IsBusy)
    //{
    //    worker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    //}
    if (lblHired.Text == "Hiring")
    {
        con.Open();
        if (Label3.Text == "Approved")
        {
            UpdatePanel2.ChildrenAsTriggers = false;

            lblHired.Text = "Hired";
            Panel3.Visible = false;
        }
     }
```

My aspx code is as follows:-

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">                
            <ContentTemplate>                                         
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="True" width="100%" Height="250px" AutoPostBack="False" style="margin-left:10px;resize:none;font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:14px;" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="True" ></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SendButton" EventName="Click" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ChatTextTimer" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>  

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" Visible="false" runat="server" style="height: 160px; position: absolute; width: 339px; opacity: 1; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 126); border: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); border-radius: 15px; padding: 46spx 16px 38px 14px; left: 20px;top:20px;">

            <div>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/loading.gif" style="margin-left:151px;" />

                <br />
                <br />
            </div>

        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Does the text in `lblHired` change to "Hired" correctly?

Comment: Yes it is changing perfectly

Comment: Strange. Could you show us the relevant parts of your aspx markup page?

Comment: @JWLim I Edited My Question. Please look at it